# sqlite error database is locked when using sqlite3 command line

Tags: sqlite, locked

I use sqlite3 command line, from bash.

I spawn multiple processes, all trying to insert into the same sqlite database file.

I often get "database is locked".

According to my reading of documentation (http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseIsLocked) , this should never happen: "SQLITE_LOCKED means the source of contention is internal and comes from the same database connection that received the SQLITE_LOCKED error".

sqlite3 command line is single-threaded, so I would expect SQLITE_BUSY in this situation, but not SQLITE_LOCKED.

Code:

```
doit() {
   sqlite3 /tmp/db "insert into foo(a,b,c) values(1,2,3);
}

doit &; doit &; doit &
```

I tried adding PRAGMA busy_timeout=2000; and  PRAGMA locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE; for the heck of it, but it didn't help.

```
sqlite3 -version
3.8.9 2015-04-08 12:16:33 8a8ffc862e96f57aa698f93de10dee28e69f6e09
```

Answer (score 9):

The error message for SQLITE_BUSY *is* "database is locked"; SQLITE_LOCKED would be "database table is locked".

The following works for me (where no `busy_timeout` would result in errors):

```
doit() {
   sqlite3 /tmp/db "pragma busy_timeout=20000; insert into foo(a,b,c) values(1,2,3);"
}
```

Comment: Hmm. You are probably right. Call it message confusion. I was now able to achieve the same effect by either: sqlite3 -init <(echo .timeout 20000)   or  PRAGMA busy_timeout=20000;   Do you know if .timeout instruction is equivalent to that pragma?

Comment: `.timeout` is exactly the same.

Answer (score 5):

There's a [good answer for this problem on DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47920). It boils down to running `.timeout 1000` at initialization to tell the command line tool to wait 1 second to acquire a lock. I'm not sure if this timeout is the same as the `pragma busy_tmeout` you reference or if it's different.